# How to check list of objects are in same hierarchy in Java

Tags: java

Below are the few classes.

1. Class B extends A
2. Class C extends B
3. Class D extends B.
4. Class Y extends X
5. Class Z extends Y

Here A,B,C,D are in same hierarchy(i.e. B,C,D are sub classes of A) and X,Y and Z are different hierarchy(i.e X hierarchy).

I have two list of objects.

```
List 1 contains (C,D,B,A)
List 2 Contains (X,Y,Z)
List 3 contains (C,X,B,A)
```

How to find all the elements in a list are in same hierarchy.
for Example List 1, List 2 Objects are in same hierarchy  and List 3 Objects are in different hierarchy.

```
public boolean checAllObjectsAreinSameHierarchy(List list){

  return true; // For List 1 and List 2
  return false; // For List 3
}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing types like this in the first place?

Comment: Why can't you use a generic list in the first place? `List<A>` will only contain objects of type `A` or subtype of `A`.

Comment: Yes i.e. is correct if i am inserting the objects. But  I want to check the elements that are already added into the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As such, I would suggest to use a generic list (that has been in existence for a decade now).

But somehow, if you're working with some legacy code, you can use [`Class#isAssignableFrom()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) method across each list element. At the same time, maintain the current super-class for each iteration.

This method should work:

```
private static boolean isInSameHierarchy(List list) {
    Class<?> clazz = null;
    for (Object obj : list) {
      if (clazz == null) {
        clazz = obj.getClass();
      } else {
        if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())) {
          continue;
        } else if (obj.getClass().isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
          clazz = obj.getClass();
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getClass() then then traverse up the hierarchy recursively calling getSuperClass(). Check if the intersection between the anspcestors of two classes (including their class) has more than Java.lang.Object in it.

That is

```
For Every pair in the list
  Compute ancestors for each
  Compute intersection of ancestors
  If size of intersection is just one then
     Not in same hierarch
  Else continue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean checAllObjectsAreinSameHierarchy(List list) {
    if (list.size() <= 1) { //At most only one entry, obviously true
        return true;
    }
    for (int c = 0; c < list.size();c+=2) {
        int comparisonOffset = 1;
        if (c == list.size() - 1) { // On last record, compare to previous
            comparisonOffset = -1
        }
        if (!(list.get(c) instanceof list.get(c + comparisonOffset).getClass() 
                || list.get(c + comparisonOffset) instanceof list.get(c).getClass())) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I think you need to compare each to the other's class in both directions to make sure that it's one is the parent of the other or vice versa.  I also put some logic for there being only one entry in the list as well as to handle an odd number of records so the last record would have to check against the previous one.

I didn't test this code, but it does seem like it should work.

Answer (score -1):

```
int countA = 0;
for(Object o : list) {
    if(o instanceof A) {
        countA++;
    }
}
return countA == list.size(); // homogenous list
```

Comment: This is not general. It does not handle the case where the hierarchy has branches.

Comment: Answers are always stronger if you also explain the solution.

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.